# TextView doesn't expand to match the TableRow height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

How do I stretch the `TextView` so it fills the entire `TableRow` height? Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting right now,

[image]

I want the `TextView` to expand with the `TableRow`.

Here is how I create the row:

```
row = new TableRow(this);

desc = new TextView(this);

desc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borders);
desc.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);  
desc.setText("Production Date");
desc.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

String date = gendataObj.getString("date");
text = new TextView(this);
text.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borders);
text.setText(date);
text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
text.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

row.addView(desc);
row.addView(text);

table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: try to change text size...
If you are using your text size  android:textSize="50dp" then change it to 60, 70...And check that which one solves your problem...

Comment: @AnilBhatiya Why would he want to change the text size in order to make `View` appear larger (not it's text)? He can just set it's height to `MATCH_PARENT` and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
text.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

to:

```
text.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Because otherwise, you don't specify height (just width), which by default will remain as `WRAP_CONTENT` which causes your `TextView` to be as heigh as it's content (text).